# jsonp and callback function name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

After reading [JSONP Explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about/2067584#2067584) I still have some questions.

1) What happens if you don't supply a callback function name, you just supply `?callback=?` ?

2) What happens if you supply a callback function name, but you don't have a function with the same name declared in your code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery will replace **?** char with a callback function name.
That name must be the function name in response to make jsonp request working.

```
$.getJSON('url/?callback=?').success(function(response){
    // Process response data;
});
```

Wil call e.g.

```
http://url/?callback=jQuery325412324_2343224
```

Then your server need to send back a callback like

```
jQuery325412324_2343224(['JSON_DATA'])
```

Comment: Do you have access to the JSON_DATA in the success function ?

Comment: Yes .success is called when call was successfull and response contain the JSON data

Answer (score 1):

1.) That's actually up to the server handling the request.

2.) You get an *"Uncaught ReferenceError"* in your browser. That is the same as this snippet for example:

```
// b nowhere defined!
b();
```